# It does not work in ADODataSet IndexDef?

Tags: delphi, indexing, delphi-xe2, tadodataset

I am creating a persistent index ADODataSet but not order information, my code is as follows:

```
ADODataSetInforArtic.IndexDefs.Clear;
case ComboBoxOrden.AsValue of
  0: begin
       with ADODataSetInforArtic.IndexDefs.AddIndexDef do
       begin
         Name := 'DenomArtic';
         Fields := 'DenomArtic';
         if ComboBoxOrden.Buttons.Image1.Id = 59 then
           Options := [ixDescending];
         ADODataSetInforArtic.IndexName := Name;
       end;
     end;
```

What am I doing wrong?
I do it this way because it is a report I'm doing. No grid, what you have is a combo in which you choose the field that will be ordered information and another button that can select ascending or descending. I do not understand that is not working ....
I use delphi xe2
Best regards

Comment: What exactly isn't working for you? I have very similar code that works perfectly, and you haven't explained exactly what problem you're having with the above code. Please [edit] to make it more clear what you're asking. Thanks.

Comment: You don't say how your report is generated.  Some reporting engines can sort data themselves, so maybe that is what is overriding your index.  I'd try temporarily adding a grid your form, so you can verify whether the index is being used or not.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what ComboBox has `.AsValue` and `Buttons`?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay, the components I use in my projects so developed by independent programmers Spanish (JfControls), greatly facilitate the development and are more aesthetically cute. 
I solved my problem by using the Sort property ...

```
ADODataSet.Sort := 'CodigDenom DESC';
```

I do not understand why my previous code did not work in ADODataset. The indexDefs work wonderfully in the ClientDataSet.

Also, I use for my reports ReportBuilder

Best regards.